# Overwriting a method from another module

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, module

I am working with [jira-python](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) and want to overwrite the existing method [`Issue.update()`](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) method. However, my code is never calling the modification.

```
from jira import JIRA
from jira.resources import Issue

class Issue(Issue):
    def update(self):
        print("overwritten")
        super(Issue, self).update() # I also tried super().update()

jira = JIRA("...")  # holds a reference to the JIRA instance
issues = jira.search_issues("")  # holds a list of JIRA Issues

for issue in issues:
    // I would expect this call to print "overwritten"
    issue.update()
```

Comment: Why would you expect your subclass to be used at all? You could *try* monkey-patching but that is always a crapshoot.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was trying to avoid monkey-patching and hoped that overwriting the existing `Issue.update` method could be overwritten bei subclassing the `Issue class` with itself (via `class Issue(Issue):`) and redefining the existing `update()` method...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with monkey-patching unless it involves copying and pasting the original code. As a wrapper, as shown in my answer, it is not dangerous at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monkey-patch the method with a wrapper like this:

```
from jira.resources import Issue

def my_update(self):
    print('overwritten')
    original_update(self)

original_update = Issue.update
Issue.update = my_update
```